# How inspect element and find the correct element? I'm using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-inspector

I need access the menu and select an option using find_element_by_css_selector, find_element_by_name or `driver.find_elements_by_id("#####").click()` but it doesn't work, I think it's because have more than an option to select.

Here an example and below the code:

[image]

```
#Botão de mostrar descrição da cotação "hidden"
driver.find_elements_by_id("Mostrar412659").click()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and note that this is *not a discussion forum*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that there is a typo in your code.

Your code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_id("Mostrar412659").click()
```

Right code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Mostrar412659").click()
```

**Answer:**

You have to expand the select tag in order to see the options. Once you do that, you can right click on the option and copy whaterver you need to find the element.

See the picture as a example.

[image]

Bear in mind that a lot of times it's better to use the WebDriverWait class to click on a element. Like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'Cotacoes')))
elem.click()
```

**Sample code**

```
driver.find_element_by_id('Cotacoes').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Cotacoes"]/option[1]').click()
```

**Sample code 2**

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'Cotacoes')))
elem.click()

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Cotacoes"]/option[1]')))
elem.click()
```

**!! Change the XPATH and ID values to your ID and XPATH !!**

Lemme know if you have any question about it!

Comment: In this case, "Cotacoes" is just the status name but the real options are another. Below you can see properly. https://imgur.com/a/sEuIXrA how to proceed is this case?

Comment: Hello Lucas. You have to right click on the options, select copy>Copy XPath. I wil update my answer with a example